# Why does this keep on returning only one node of my singly linked list?

Tags: c

I have a structure,

```
    typedef struct song{
    string title;
    string artist;
    string album;
    string genre;
    float rating;
    struct song *next;
    }song_t;
```

and a delete function,

```
    song_t *DeleteSong(song_t *head, string key){
    song_t *temp, *temp2, *holder;
    holder = (song_t *)malloc(sizeof(song_t));  
    temp = head;


    while(temp != NULL && strcasecmp(temp->title, key) != 0){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(temp == NULL){
        newline;
        printf("Song not found.");
        newline;
        newline;
    }

    else if(temp == head){
        if(temp->next == NULL){
            temp->next = NULL;
            free(temp);
            return NULL;
        }
        else{
        head = temp->next;
        }
    }

    else if(temp->next == NULL){
        temp2 = head;

        while(temp2->next->next != NULL){
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        holder = temp2->next->next;
        temp2->next = NULL;
    }

    else{
        temp2 = head;
        while(temp2->next != temp){
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        holder = temp;
        temp2->next = temp->next;
        free(holder);
    }
    return head;
    }
```

and finally, a remove duplicate function,

```
song_t *RemoveDuplicate(song_t *head){
    song_t *temp;
    song_t *temp2;
    temp = head;
    temp2 = temp->next;

    while(temp != NULL){
        while(temp2 != NULL){
            if(strcasecmp(temp->title,temp2->title) == 0 && strcasecmp(temp->artist,temp2->artist) == 0 && strcasecmp(temp->album,temp2->album) == 0 && strcasecmp(temp->genre,temp2->genre) == 0){
                if(temp2 == temp->next){
                    temp = DeleteSong(temp,temp2->title);
                }
                else{
                    temp2 = DeleteSong(temp2->next,temp2->title);
                }
            }
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    }
```

However, whenever I include the remove duplicate function in main, 
    head = RemoveDuplicate(head);

the result always returns only one structure and removes the whole list. I think that there is something wrong with the RemoveDuplicate function because I tested the DeleteSong function and it works well.

Comment: In the else statement I don't understand why you are passing temp2->next as head pointer. 
And after the `temp=temp->next` (after the inner while) shouldn't you put `temp2=temp->next;`?

Answer (score 0):

If the first two entries in the list are duplicates, then it seems that the first time you check for:

```
if(temp2 == temp->next){
    temp = DeleteSong(temp,temp2->title);
}
```

it will evaluate as true at the head of the list. You may want to check what happens from there if your list is suddenly reduced to just the head of your list.

I suspect the error may actually be found in the DeleteSong function, because it looks a bit more complicated to me than I recall from other singly-linked lists that I've seen.

In pseudo-C, I'd probably attempt something like this:

```
to_delete = find_node_by_key( key )
return if to_delete == null

current = head
last    = null

if to_delete == current
{
    head = current->next
    to_mem_free = current
}
else do
{
    if to_delete == current
    {
        to_mem_free = current
        if ( last != null ) last->next = current->next
        break
    }

    last = current

} while (current = current->next) != null
```

You can combine the search for the node to delete with the actual deletion so you won't have to traverse the list twice. You may also want to try to avoid using "temp" as a variable name unless absolutely necessary because it often causes confusion.

Many tool chains include a library that provides singly-linked lists. You can save yourself hours of coding and debugging by using such a library, which probably also provide sorted trees or hash lists that significantly speed up searching for, e.g., song titles.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder = (song_t *)malloc(sizeof(song_t));
/* snip */
/* else if */
    holder = temp2->next->next;
/* else */
    holder = temp;
    temp2->next = temp->next;
    free(holder);
```

When you assign `holder = temp2->next->next;` (incidentally, that's always `NULL` there), or `holder = temp;`, you're losing your reference to the `malloc`ed memory. Since you're not really using `holder` at all, the fix is to remove it from the function. In the first case, you're not using it in any way except to assign a complicated `NULL`, in the second case, removing `holder = temp;` and `free`ing `temp` is the correct way.

There are a few more strange things and mistakes:

```
song_t *DeleteSong(song_t *head, string key){
    song_t *temp, *temp2, *holder;
    holder = (song_t *)malloc(sizeof(song_t));  // as said, remove holder completely
    temp = head;

    /* Find song with given title */
    while(temp != NULL && strcasecmp(temp->title, key) != 0){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(temp == NULL){
        newline;
        printf("Song not found.");
        newline;
        newline;
    }
    /* It's the very first in the list */
    else if(temp == head){
        if(temp->next == NULL){
            /* It's even the only one */
            temp->next = NULL;    // This runs only if temp->next is already NULL
            free(temp);           // Also free the members of temp, or you're leaking
            return NULL;
        }
        else{
            head = temp->next;    // You should now free temp and members, or you're leaking memory
        }
    }
    /* It's the last one in the list, but not the first */
    else if(temp->next == NULL){
        temp2 = head;
        /* Find the penultimate song */
        while(temp2->next->next != NULL){
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        holder = temp2->next->next;
        temp2->next = NULL;    // You should now free temp and members, or you're leaking memory
    }
    /* Neither first nor last */
    else{
        temp2 = head;
        /* Find song before */
        while(temp2->next != temp){
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        holder = temp;
        temp2->next = temp->next;
        free(holder);
    }
    return head;
}
```

but apart from the leaks, it is correct, though unnecessarily complicated.

```
song_t *DeleteSong(song_t *head, string key) {
    song_t *prev = NULL, curr = head;
    /* Find song and node before that */
    while(curr != NULL && strcasecmp(curr->title, key) != 0) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (curr == NULL) {
        /* Not found */
        newline;
        printf("Song not found.");
        newline;
        newline;
    } else if (prev == NULL) {
        /* It's the very first song in the list
         * so let head point to its successor
         * and free the song; it doesn't matter
         * if it's the last in the list
         */
        head = curr->next;
        free(curr->title);   // Probably, but not if title isn't malloced
        free(curr->artist);  // Ditto
        free(curr->album);
        free(curr->genre);
        free(curr);
    } else {
        /* We have a predecessor, let that point
         * to the successor and free the song
         */
        prev->next = curr->next;
        free(curr->title); // See above
        free(curr->artist);
        free(curr->album);
        free(curr->genre);
        free(curr);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Your `RemoveDuplicate` function on the other hand does not do what you intend. Apart from the distinction between the cases where the duplicate immediately follows the original and where it doesn't, for which I can see no reason, the assignments `temp = DeleteSong(temp,temp2->title);` resp. `temp2 = DeleteSong(temp2->next,temp2->title);` change what `temp` resp. `temp2` point to, but not where the respective predecessor in the list points. Let's illustrate the problem with a little ASCII art:

```
       temp    temp2
         |      |
         v      v
song1->song2->song3->song4->song5->...
```

where `song2` and `song3` are duplicates. Now in `temp = DeleteSong(temp,temp2->title);`, since the two songs are duplicates, the `head` argument of `DeleteSong` already matches, and in your version of `DeleteSong`, `head = temp->next; return head;` is all that is done, so the list is not changed at all, you just get

```
            temp temp2
              |   |
              v   v
song1->song2->song3->song4->...
```

both pointers pointing to the same list node. In my version of `DeleteSong` that frees the node, `song1.next` would now point to `free`d memory, ouch.

If the duplicate doesn't immediately follow the original, `temp2 = DeleteSong(temp2->next,temp2->title);` may not find a song with matching title, since the search starts *after* the known match, in which case the list is not modified at all, and `temp2` is just changed to point to the successor. If there is a song with matching title after that, the found duplicate is still not removed from the list, and the part after that may be changed, possibly leading to an unsound state. If `temp2` points to the penultimate node in the list, and the last node has a matching title, the last node is `free`d, but the `next` pointer of what was the duplicate isn't changed, so now it points to `free`d memory, you have a dangling pointer (that's a segfault waiting to happen).

A further problem is that the criteria for removal in `DeleteSong` and `RemoveDuplicate` are different, in the former, you check only the title, in the latter also artist, album and genre, so using the former function in the latter risks deleting songs that should not be deleted (consider cover versions).

When you want to delete a node from a singly linked list, you need a pointer to the preceding node to be able to change what that points to, or you'll create dangling pointers. I have given a standard way to do that above, you can basically copy that into the inner loop, but here it can never happen that we want to remove the first node, so it's a bit simpler:

```
// void, since head is never changed, only duplicates after the original are removed
void RemoveDuplicates(song_t *head) {
    song_t *orig = head, prev, curr;
    while(orig != NULL && orig->next != NULL) {
        prev = orig;
        curr = orig->next;
        while(curr != NULL) {
            // Find next song to remove
            while(curr != NULL && !meets_deletion_criteria(orig, curr)) {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            // Now either curr is NULL, or it shall be deleted
            if (curr != NULL) {
                // Let the predecessor point to curr's successor
                prev->next = curr->next;
                clean_up(curr); // free all malloced members and the node itself
                curr = prev->next;
            }
        }
        orig = orig->next;
    }
}
```